# global path display is shorter than use to be

Tags: rviz, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

HI

Some time ago I have the global path full display. From the robot place to the goal.

You may see the green line in the following video.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Xsv1RSE5B1A

Now, i can only see the global path inside the dinamic window area.

You may see the line in the following video
It is the blue line (i changed from green to blue, beacuse local path is green)

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ue9GBKaLC9I

I cant remember what I have done to do this change.
May anyone help me to restore the full global path display.

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/373844/global-path-display-is-shorter-than-use-to-be/) by [inaciose](https://answers.ros.org/users/48349/inaciose/) on ROS Answers with karma: 26 on 2021-03-11

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Changing the topic to be displayed from `/move_base/TrajectoryPlannerROS/global_plan` to `/move_base/NavfnROS/plan` may solve the problem.

---

Originally posted by [miura](https://answers.ros.org/users/59801/miura/) with karma: 1908 on 2021-03-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [inaciose](https://answers.ros.org/users/48349/inaciose/) on 2021-03-12**:
Solved. Thanks.

**Comment by [miura](https://answers.ros.org/users/59801/miura/) on 2021-03-13**:
@inaciose I'm glad it's resolved.
I hope you will give this answer as the best answer.

**Comment by [inaciose](https://answers.ros.org/users/48349/inaciose/) on 2021-03-13**:
@miura how can i mark this answer as the best answer?

**Comment by [miura](https://answers.ros.org/users/59801/miura/) on 2021-03-14**:
Thank you. Select the check mark below the number of votes to get the best answer.